# Multidimensional array to linear array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have here a multidimensional array.

```
  {
     "date_start": [
                   "2013-09-30",
                   "2013-09-27",
                   ],

     "time_start": [
                   "2013-09-30 08:41:00",
                   "2013-09-27 09:01:00",       
                   ],

     "time_out":   [
                   "2013-09-30 18:37:00",
                   "2013-09-27 21:11:00",
                   ],              
   }
```

Is it possible to convert this to a linear array? to something like this?

```
 {
    [{"date_start":"2013-09-30","time_start":"2013-09-30 08:41:00","time_out":"2013-09-30 18:37:00"},
     {"date_start":"2013-09-27","time_start":"2013-09-30 09:01:00","time_out":"2013-09-30 21:11:00"}]
 }
```

I'm having a hard time to think how to do it T_T. thanks for anyone who could help me.

**UPDATE:**
This is now my updated work. Thanks to Nil'z for enlightening me to use decode. Just need a little more tweek.

```
     $data_en = json_encode($data);
     $data_de = json_decode($data_en, true);
     $test = array();

     foreach($data_de as $key => $value)
     {
        echo $key."<br/>";
        foreach($value as $k => $v)
        {
            echo "$k |";
            echo json_encode($v)."<br/>";
        }   
     }
```

Here is now the output but still need to work something out:

```
date_start
0 |"2013-09-30"
1 |"2013-09-27"

time_start
0 |"2013-09-30 08:41:00"
1 |"2013-09-27 09:01:00"

time_out
0 |"2013-09-30 18:37:00"
1 |"2013-09-27 21:11:00"
```

Comment: This smells more like JSON, which after decoding could become a multidimensional array. Will this "array" always be two dimensional?

Comment: yes its json and yap it will.

Comment: the resultant json is not parsed...

Answer (score 1):

If its `JSON` try like this:

```
<?php
    $data   = array();
    $array  = json_decode( $mainArray );    #decode the JSON
    foreach( $array as $key => $each ){
        $data[$key]['date_start'] = $each['date_start'];
        $data[$key]['time_start'] = $each['time_start'];
        $data[$key]['time_out'] = $each['time_out'];
    }
    #again encode the JSON
    $data   = json_encode( $data );
    print_r( $data );
?>
```

Comment: it gives me a warning 'json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given' and 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' :(

Comment: have your replaced `$mainArray` with your `json variable` ? @bot

Comment: yes i changed it. i made a little research and your answer should be working. i only have a problem on the decode part.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try with recursive function:

```
function array_multi_to_linear($arr) {
    static $rez;
    foreach($arr as $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                array_multi_to_linear($v);
            } else {
                $rez[] =$v;
            }
    }
    return $rez;
}
```